# 'Sub Main' was not found. Service management console application error?

Tags: vb.net, service, console

There is possibly a few things wrong with the below. Haven't had a chance to test/debug the code yet as can't run it. It stating that no main method has been found. But there is? i've even changed it to shared etc. It's probably something obvious?

It's flagging - 'Sub Main' was not found in 'ConsoleApplication1.Module1' error.

Also the main method wasn't always a separate class, I was just trying stuff. I'm importing a reference  - system.processes. Was initially created as a vb.form but realised i didn't want the form part and recreated as a console app (which is very possibly where the problem lies as it's one of the first console apps i've done).

Code is basically planned to act on a service dying. Report and try and manage the restart (not finished, ideas welcome).

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO

Module Module1


Public Class Control


    Public Sub Main()              'Public Sub Main(ByVal sArgs() As String)
        Dim restart As New Rest

        restart.startTime = DateTime.Now()
        restart.cr20Services()
        restart.Report()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Rest
    public startTime As String
    Dim logPath As String = "C:\cr20\restart.txt"
    'Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile)
    Dim arrcr20ServicesInitialStatus As New ArrayList
    Dim failedServices As New ArrayList
    Dim arrcr20Services As New ArrayList


    Public Sub cr20Services()

        'cr20 Services
        arrcr20Services.Add("cr20 service")
        arrcr20Services.Add("cr20 router")


        For Each cr20Service In arrcr20Services

            arrcr20ServicesInitialStatus.Add(cr20Service & " - " & cr20Status(cr20Service))
            cr20Restore(cr20Service)

        Next


    End Sub

    Private Function cr20Status(ByVal cr20Service As String)

        Dim service As ServiceController = New ServiceController(cr20Service)

        Return service.Status.ToString


    End Function



    Private Sub cr20Restore(ByVal cr20Service As String)

        Dim service As ServiceController = New ServiceController(cr20Service)

        'Dim p() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("calc") 

        If (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) Or (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)) Then

            failedServices.Add(service)
            service.Stop()
            Thread.Sleep(10000)     'give service 10 seconds to stop
            service.Start()

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: It needs to be Shared if you put it in a class.  And you have to tell the compiler about it: Project + Properties, Application tab, Startup object setting.

Comment: Ahhhhh you're dead right (knew the shared bit was just trying different things as couldn't understand it not working).

Answer was  - you have to tell the compiler about it: Project + Properties, Application tab, Startup object setting